# Layout bug: tags in text, line spacing

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Tags in text cause uneven line spacing. Example (there is too much space below the line with the tag):

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo [consequat](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/consequat). Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

Comment: Someone should post a question with the tag [consequat]!

Comment: Is this Latin? :S

Comment: @Hsien-Chih: This particular text is called [lorem ipsum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorem_ipsum).  It is based on Latin but not in real Latin.

Comment: I will put in a fix tonight.

Comment: @Jin: It does not seem that this has been fixed yet (at least not on Meta).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have put in a fix for this. It will be in the next deployment.

Comment: Looks good, thanks!